# Change div background by clicking on another div

Tags: jquery, css, toggleclass

Hi I am trying to change a div to white when another div is clicked on. Sounds simple but cannot get it to work. Any ideas ?

```
<section id=maindisplay>
   <div id=control></div>
</section>


$("#control").click(function(){ 
$("#maindisplay").toggleClass('#maindisplay_white');
```

The CSS

```
#maindisplay{
background-color:black;
height: 670px;
width: 1109px;
}

#maindisplay_white{
background-color:white;
}

#control{
cursor:pointer;
background-color:white;
width: 17px;
height: 52px;
}
```

Comment: `#` is for IDs, `.` is for classes. `toggleClass` should have neither prefix, and will make it match the CSS selector which begins with a `.`. IDs are unique, and each element can only have one. Classes can be used repeatedly, and each element can have several.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#maindisplay").toggleClass('maindisplay_white');
```

with this:

```
#maindisplay.maindisplay_white{
  background-color:white;
}
```

Here's a [`--> JS Fiddle <--`](http://jsfiddle.net/L7CMS/1/) demonstrating changes.

Comment: Should it not just add the class to the existing ? Changed both to classes to test but still does not work. Cant see why, it should just overwrite the colour in the maindisplay.